# Как сблизить кнопки?

Tags: flutter, dart

Необходимо уменьшить расстояние между кнопками, хочется сделать их немного плотнее друг к другу.

```
Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              TextButton(onPressed: () => launch('tel://111'),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Icon(Icons.phone_iphone_outlined, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
                                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0),),
                                      Text('446-777',
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 16)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  TextButton(onPressed: () {
                                    openSite();
                                  },

                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.laptop_chromebook_outlined, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0),),
                                        Text('www.aaa.ru',
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 16)),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 15),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  TextButton(onPressed: () {
                                    openMaps();
                                  },
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, color: Colors.white, size: 20,),
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0),),
                                        Text('г. Москва',
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 16)),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

У `TextButton` есть `style` который принимает `ButtonStyle`. Через метод [TextButton.styleFrom](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton/styleFrom.html) мы можем определить `minimumSize` и `padding`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: Size(50, 0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.phone_iphone_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white, size: 20),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0),
                ),
                Text('446-777',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: Size(50, 0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.laptop_chromebook_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white, size: 20),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0),
                ),
                Text('www.aaa.ru',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 15),
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: Size(50, 0),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.location_on_outlined,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 20,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0),
                ),
                Text('г. Москва',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```